# google App script Admin Directory user list against orgUnitPath with apostrophe OU name

Tags: google-apps-script

I got errors either Invalid Input: INVALID_OU_ID or Invalid Input
problem at line **query: "orgUnitPath='OU NAME WITH SINGLE QUOTE'"**
i tried "orgUnitPath='/Bill\'s OU'" and "orgUnitPath='/Bill\\'s OU'" without luck

```
function LastLoginReport() {
  var pageToken, page;

  do {
    page = AdminDirectory.Users.list({
      domain: my.domain,
      query: "orgUnitPath='/Bill\'s OU'",
      pageToken: pageToken
    });
    var users = page.users;
    }
    pageToken = page.nextPageToken;
  } while (pageToken);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a single backslash to escape the single quote.

This is from the official documentation [documentation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/search-users):

> Surround with single quotes ' if the query contains whitespace. Escape
>   single quotes in queries with \', for example 'Valentine\'s Day'.

so therefore, the line you're looking to use is:

```
query: 'orgUnitPath=/Bill\'s OU'
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I'd read the API reference many time. Also tried the way Google suggest. But I'm still getting "Invalid Input: INVALID_OU_ID".
I test on this site: https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/list
i tried:
    query: 'orgUnitPath=/Bill\'s OU'
    query: "orgUnitPath='/Bill\'s OU'"
    query: 'orgUnitPath="/Bill\'s OU"'
    query: 'orgUnitPath="/Bill\\'s OU"'

Comment: You're right, I can't get it to work either. Maybe submit this to the issue tracker and remove the apostrophe from the OU in the admin panel

Comment: i'd reported this issues today. Thanks for your help!
https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=3591